# CDN Module, CDN Mapping for multiple source domains

Tags: 7, cdn

I have a Drupal 7 site with the [CDN](https://www.drupal.org/project/cdn) module working nicely (with MaxCDN). The CDN mapping is working perfectly for mapping all of my assets to the pull zone. Additionally, I have images on the site that are loaded from a third party (real estate listing images). How can I configure images from that domain to have a second CDN mapping configuration (I have a pull zone created for this second domain). Thank you for any help.